# Facebook messenger integration on a custom web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to integrate Facebook messenger into my react web app. The goal is to enable chatting between registered users (login is done through Facebook api).

I tried using url (https://m.me/${username}) which will redirect to a user you want to chat with. Unfortunately, graph api doesn't support this anymore. Reading Facebook documentation i was unable to find anything about chatting between two users, just chat-bots.

Can messenger api be integrated like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can messenger api be integrated like this?

No, it can not. Messenger API is for communication between a page and a user.

There is no officially supported way to provide user-to-user chats.